# How to know which trace is coming from which program

Tags: networking, wireshark

I run Wireshark but how do I know which of these thousands of trace lines is related to the program I am interested in ?
I only want to see `WCF` services from my `WPF` program. Or just how can I filter that to only show `WCF` services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not yet possible to achieve with Wireshark, not that there hasn't been interest in it.  In fact, there is a long-standing enhancement bug request open for this feature, namely [Bug 1184](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1184).

That said, I believe it is possible to obtain this information using either [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) or its predecessor [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865).